# create-react-app errors are showing as bundle.js line numbers and wepback.config.js isn't fixing mapping

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I am running a create-react-app locally with the command `npm start` which from package.json, runs `react-scripts start` and react is version 18.1.0.

For errors in the project, I am getting hard to track down errors due to them pointing me to things such as:
`ContentPage@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10910:5`

rather than the original file.

I figured I needed to add a source map to the project, and since there was no webpack.config.js file in the root directory (inside the parent of src/) I added one and set this to the contents:

```js
module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

But on running `npm start` again, there is no change in the error logging.

What steps should I take to get source map to work on my app?

Answer (score 0):

Using 'eval-source-map' solved the problem for me.

Comment: What is 'eval-source-map'?